# How to override output filepath and write it along with output files at a desired directory through argparse

Tags: python, numpy, command-line-interface, argparse

I have the following example code and I use `argparse` to call and execute it.

```
#test1.py
import numpy
from in_para import *
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

nx = 31
dx = 2 / (nx - 1)
nt = 20   
D = 0.3  
sigma = .2 
dt = sigma * dx**2 / D 

u = numpy.ones(nx)      
u[int(.5 / dx):int(1 / dx + 1)] = 2  

un = numpy.ones(nx) 

for n in range(nt):  
    un = u.copy() 
    for i in range(1, nx - 1):
        u[i] = un[i] + D * dt / dx**2 * (un[i+1] - 2 * un[i] + un[i-1])
        
def test1():
    for i in range(nx):
        print(i,u[i])
        f = open('Output.txt', 'w')
        print(i,u[i], file = f)
    plt.plot(numpy.linspace(0, 2, nx), u)
    plt.savefig('test1.png', bbox_inches='tight')
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test1()
```

Below is the `main.py` script where I call the above code via `argparse`

```
import numpy
from test1 import *
import argparse
import sys

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser() 
    parser.add_argument('-C','--Modul',type=str, help='Choose of the component', default=None)
    args = vars(parser.parse_args())
 
    if args['Modul'] == 'test':
        print("This is output for test1:")
        test1()
   
          
if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Since I'm working on a python pipeline, I would like to override the output filepath and give it via CLI, i.e., as an `arseparse` argument. As I've said in the beginning, the `test1.py` is an example code, in reality it will have several lines of code and I dont want the user of `main.py` to go inside and modify it manually. Thus, my question is, can the output filepath be overridden via `argparse` ?  such that I can collect the outputs from `test1.py` and write the  `.txt and .png file` at a desired directory and desired filenames. For example, the command line should look like this:

```
python3 main.py -C test -O [Output options]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it adding this line to `main.py`:

```
import os
parser.add_argument('-O','--Output',type=str, help='Output Directory', default="./Output")
output_dir = args['Output']
if not os.path.exists(output_dir):
    os.makedirs(output_dir)
```

After that pass output directory to test function:

```
test1(output_dir)
```

Change the test function to accept the output directory and change the path in `plt.savefig`

```
def test1(output_dir):
    for i in range(nx):
        print(i,u[i])
        f = open('Output.txt', 'w')
        print(i,u[i], file = f)
    plt.plot(numpy.linspace(0, 2, nx), u)
    plt.savefig(os.path.join(output_dir, 'test1.png'), bbox_inches='tight')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Followed the solution, but I get an error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test_output/test1.png'` when I use `python3 diff_1D.py -C Script1 -O test_output`

Comment: Please make sure the that `test_output` directory is already present before running the code

Comment: It is a workaround, but does not give the liberty to do stuff (make directory as well as modify output file names) in CLI

Comment: please see the updated changes in the response, including the flexibility to create the directory after checking for it's existence.

Comment: @newstudent please add this code segment in `main.py` to create the directory:
`if not os.path.exists(output_dir):`
    `os.makedirs(output_dir)`